# Artifact feed for entire organization?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have many related projects in my organization.  When I create an artifact (nuget package) for any project I want to publish that package to a single organization-level feed.

I also want all my projects to consume packages from this feed.

Is this possible?

I currently reference feeds from projects I need to reference as shown in the YAML below - which does not work.  With respect to the first question I asked above, what is the correct way to reference packages I need to consume from my local feeds?

```
task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'Domain.Project/OtherProject@Local'
    publishVstsFeed: 'Domain.Project/OtherProject@Local'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we can create an organization-scoped feed in Artifacts:

[image]

Then specify your local package path and target feed location in nuget push task, for example:

[image]

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '..\xx\NuGetPackage\xx.0.0.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: 'xxxx'
```

Run the pipeline with the self-hosted agent to push the local package to the organization scope feed of azure artifact.

**Default** pool: Use it to register [self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops) that you've set up.

```
pool:
  name: Default
```